# HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available when use Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

> Hi Guys , i got following error when I Iterate List and Store in
>   DataBase Using Thread ,  error come into picture after inserting 1,000
>   records

**error :**

```
 "Thread-2614" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction;

    java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30080ms.

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

**My Code**

```
while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {

                            DimCompany comp = new DimCompany();
                            Row row = rowIt.next();
                            Cell c = row.getCell(cmpName);
                            if (c != null && c.getCellType() != c.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                                if (cmpName != null && row.getCell(cmpName) != null) {
                                    comp.setCompanyName(row.getCell(cmpName).toString());
                                    comp.setSourecLevel1("MCA");
                                }
                                if (cmpUId != null && row.getCell(cmpUId) != null) {
                                    comp.setCompanyUniqueId(row.getCell(cmpUId).toString());
                                }
                                if (compType != null && row.getCell(compType) != null) {
                                    comp.setCompType(row.getCell(compType).toString());
                                }
                                if (foundedDate != null && row.getCell(foundedDate) != null) {
                                    comp.setFoundedDate(row.getCell(foundedDate).toString());
                                }

                              //save record
                              int i = parseDataDao.saveCompany(comp);
                      }
                      }
                    };
                    t1.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
    }
```

Comment: I think this is not Threading problem it is connection pool configuration problem.Can you share Hikari pool configuration you are using.I think some timeout happening during your connection idle.

Comment: actually , i am not configured Hikari pool in my application , in which file we can configure Hikar pool ? i am use Spring Boot Framework

Comment: application.properties or applicaton.yaml file

Comment: but If i add  t1.sleep(20); then its work properly , but i want some different solution

Comment: check your database properties

Answer (score 0):

**Unbounded thread creation** is the main problem in your code.

By default Hikari has a pool size of 10 connections. You can increase it using:

```
hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(...);
```

You are creating over a thousand threads and running them at once. These are much more in number than the hikari pool size (whatever you have set, or the default as above). So your queries wait in queue to acquire a connection and eventually timeout.

You should use a thread pool. The easiest way to quickly do it is to use:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {/* contents of your run method here */});
```

This will use the ForkJoin common pool. You can fine tune it by using an [implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) of the [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: sorry , but its not work in my code , can you please suggest me another solution

Comment: @AMARMAGAR what do you mean by not work? Are you getting the same error? If yes, can you edit your question to add your new code at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ThreadPool of 10 threads and submit your tasks to it, like below

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
executorService.submit(task1);
```

This will make sure your task runs async and running out of connections do not happen

Comment: sorry , but its not work in my code , can you please suggest me another solution

Comment: Create the Executor service outside the while loop, and do this executorService.submit(t1); in place of t1.start()

Comment: but If i add t1.sleep(20); then its work properly , but i want some different solution